# How to calcule differences between two codes in python

Tags: python, comments, whitespace, checksum, difference

I'm trying to find differences between two codes without considering the comments and the withespaces. I tried to use checksum, but it considers irrelevant changes. How can I do a checksum in a smart way using python?

Thanks

Comment: I would consider using a diff tool (like git) and parsing the results into python. For example: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff You will need to find the diffs, then use python to decide which ones are whitespace.

Comment: Why don't you use a software like winmerge for exemple ?

If you really want to do it with python, you should compare each lines that do not start with "#", maybe do something like `"".join(string.split())"` in order to remove whitespaces

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use git diff also. I'll see the software winmerge. Thank you !!